# Length of numeric values in SAS

Tags: sas

I tried with different length for numeric variables. I referred below link

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/63285/HTML/default/viewer.htm#numvar.htm

where it is given that largest integer that can be represented with length 3 is 8192.

I tried the sample program below. I have declared a variable num with length 3. And tried storing different values which exceeds 8192.

```
data numeric_values;
    input num;
    length num 3;
    datalines;
    8194
    8192
    8193
    9000
    10000
    10008
    ;
run;
```

I am not getting any error after executing this program.

Dataset numeric_values got created with all the values
8194
8192
8192
9000
10000
10008

Can someone please explain me the concept of length in numeric data type. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SAS stores numbers as [floating points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point).  The largest integer that can *safely* be held in length 3 may be 8192, but larger values can also be stored, with a loss of precision.  In your example, you can see that 8193 is actually be corrupted to 8192.  Your other example numbers are even, which happen to be safe up to a higher threshold, but if you picked 10009 as an example, you'd see it gets corrupted too, into 10008.

It is interesting that SAS doesn't offer any warnings or notes when this happens.  I guess they've decided the burden is on the programmer to be aware of tricks of floating point notation.

[Edited answer to refer specifically to integers, in light of DWal's important comment.]

Comment: Keep in mind, those are the largest _integers_ that can be safely stored. If you've got digits to the right of the decimal point, you're not going to go very far with 3 bytes.